# Redirect doesn't work in cake 3 when I use copy command before

Tags: redirect, cakephp, copy

I tried this in cake 3:

```
$path = '/some/path/on/myserver';
$dir = new Folder($path, true, 0775);
copy('https://www.domain.com/image',$path.$imgName);
return $this->redirect('redirectPath');
```

$this->redirect doesn't work. But if I command out the copy command redirect works fine. What is the problem or did I miss something?

Comment: I think you are getting some error while your copy function gets executed and due to that error, a header is sent to the browser, because of which the page does not redirects. Try debugging the copy command. What I can see is what is $imgName here? This variable does not seems to be declared. That could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If any error or warning happend before `$this->redirect()` it will not work, it will show

> **Header already sent** error

if you want to force to redirect then you may use

```
$this->response = $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']) ;
$this->response->send () ;
die ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

`$this->redirect($this->referer(['action' => 'index']));`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all answers and please don't mind. But I think there is no easy solution!
Cause after sending this copy(..) statement the http request will be finished. And the browser will not get any response and will wait till Skt. Nevermind... ;-)
The only solution is to call another view and from there start an ajax request.
In this ajax request you may start your copy statement. Or if you have gearman running start a worker to do this.

Thanks anyway.

Michael